# why req.body is undefined using body parser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I am making `post` request but I am getting `req.body` is `undefined`.
here is my sever.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/hockey');
var playerModel = require('./model/players')

var app = express();
var port = process.env.port || 3000;
var appRouter = express.Router();
app.use('/api', appRouter);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
appRouter.route('/player')
    .post((req, res) => {
    // undefined why ?
    console.log(req.body);
        var player = new playerModel(req.body);
       // player.save();
        res.status(201).send(player);
    })
    .get((req, res) => {
        playerModel.find((err, player) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                res.json(player);

            }
        })
        // res.json({"name": "nave"})
    })


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("helo")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening to port', port)
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Mongos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel server.js -o index.js && node index"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.9"
  }
}
```

when I used `postman` and send post request it show me `undefined`

[image]

**Model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var playerModel = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    lastname: {type: String}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('players', playerModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the order of the middleware:

```
app.use('/api', appRouter);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The order of middleware loading is important: middleware functions that are loaded first are also executed first.

Move `app.use('/api', appRouter);`, as shown below:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));    
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', appRouter);
```

Answer (score 2):

To further add to Aleksey's answer, you were telling `app` to pass all requests to the `app` through the body-parser middleware, but not the `appRouter`, which was what was handling the /api/player post request.

Aleksey's answer is great, another way to could be for just the `appRouter` to use the `body-parser`,

```
app.use('/api', appRouter);
appRouter.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));    
appRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Read more about using [Express Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)